# Processing photos uploaded by IOS gives different results

Tags: python, ios, azure

I'm writing this post as my last bullet to solve the mistery of what is going on here.

Essentially, I'm developing an IOS app which will upload a set of photos to Azure, and they will be processed with AI and Image processing in a Batch service.

The app should upload the images to an azure Function, which will trigger the batch service in which all the processing is done, then the results are stored in an storage account.

All of the tests I have done so far have been succesful processing images from local, or even making my PC to download them from the cloud and process them as same encoding/decoding steps until the process begin.

The problem starts when I do the entire process, just including the front end part, with the only difference that the images are uploaded from IOS instead of my PC to the function, it gives entirely different (and wrong) results.

Things I have tested until now:

- The most relevant thing I can tell, I have downloaded a set of photos previously uploaded by IOS, I have reuploaded from my PC and the results were correct again, so the exact same images, the exact same process, gives really diferent results.
- The quality encoder of IOS app is set to 1/1.
- The RGB values from an image uploaded by IOS and the same image uploaded locally differ in no more than +-3-5... That couldnt lead to the results I am getting.

Code I use to begin the process.

```
generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs(container_name)
front = block_blob_service._get_blob(container_name, blob.name)
b64_bytes_front = np.frombuffer(front.content, dtype=np.uint8)
opencv_front = cv.imdecode(b64_bytes_front, cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
img = opencv_front
```

As I said, I use the same code to download to my PC (imwrite at the end)

I dont know what else to do, is there anyone here that had a similar experience?

Thank you so much.

EDIT. Im aware of all that opencv RGB-BGR standard. The channels are right, I think It has more to do with the decoding process of an image firstly recognized as jpeg (from azure), and the same image (not)recognized as Octet-application, as it shows when I upload it from IOS. Im starting to guess that this doesnt have solution since I'm talking about natural loss from encoding/decoding steps, but the differences in the processing are too big

Comment: I forgot to mention that when I use IO's to upload, the image shows application/octet-stream as type of content, while it shows "image/jpeg" if I download the same image and reupload to Azure from my PC.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this line: opencv_front = cv.imdecode(b64_bytes_front, cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
which I assume means you are using openCV and doing something with color? I had a problem with this a while ago, and discovered that openCV stores color values internally as BGR instead of RGB. It does, however, expect the input to be RGB unless you tell it otherwise, and will automatically revert the format back to RGB if you use any of openCV's file write functions.
Now, the reason I believe that it affects your IOS app: the BGR format is used by openCV because it is a format used by digital cameras! (The reason can be read here: https://www.learnopencv.com/why-does-opencv-use-bgr-color-format/) My guess is that IOS photos/images are stored as BGR and if you send them via the app, they are sent as BGR (as is) while when you export them to your PC, the IOS software converts it to RGB so your photos don't look weird when you try to view them on a PC - this would explain why downloading to your PC and then reuploading fixes the issue.

Hope this helped somehow!

Comment: Please add this to your question then, as it is not clear what kind of problem or error you are actually encountering.

Comment: added! Thank you